# How to implement the pre and post holidays effects in Time series modeling using Prophet or Seasonal Arima in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have implemented the new package "Prophet" in R for my daily sales data. It's easy to implement a flag variable for holidays but I want to predict the effect of these holidays on the prior Fridays or post Tuesdays. I should expect lower sales for the Fridays before the long weekend but don't see that happening and the accuracy is too bad. Is there a way I can create a new variable including these fridays?  I am ok to implement that in a Seasonal Arima as well.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code.

Comment: I have tried the seasonal Arima:-                                                               
    fit<-arima(time_series[1:400],order=c(3,1,3),
                       seasonal=list(order=c(1,1,1),period= 7),method= "ML")               forecast(fit,h=14)

Comment: And also the prophet function with 3 years of data for more holiday data points.                                                                                         
 holidays_all <- bind_rows(thanksgiving, Christmas,long_weekends)     
m<- prophet(time_series[1:1430,],yearly.seasonality = T,weekly.seasonality = T,holidays = holidays_all)
future <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 90,freq 'day',include_history= F)
forecast <- predict(m, future)
prophet_plot_components(m, forecast);